# Basic command line REPL calculator

Tags: c++, regex, math-expression-eval

I'm pretty confident in this code but I want to be sure I haven't missed anything to do with optimization or error handling. The program takes input in the form of `{number} {operator} {number}` and prints the result. If the input is invalid it prints nothing.

Example input: `1.0 + 2.0`
Output: `3`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <regex>

double calculate(const double a, const char op, const double b)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '/':
            if (b == 0.0)
                throw std::invalid_argument {"Divide by zero"};
            return a / b;
        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument {{op}};
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::regex valid_input {
        "([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*) ([\\+\\-\\*\\/]) ([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*)"};

    std::string line;
    std::smatch terms;

    double a;
    double b;
    char op;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        if (!std::regex_match(line, terms, valid_input))
            continue;

        a = std::stod(terms[1]);
        b = std::stod(terms[3]);
        op = terms[2].str().front();

        std::cout << calculate(a, op, b) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping escape characters becomes confusing.
Use the appropriate string literal.

```
 // Your String
 "([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*) ([\\+\\-\\*\\/]) ([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*)"

 // A Raw String (no escape characters)
 R"RAW(([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*) ([\+\-\*\/]) ([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*))RAW"
```

Don't think your regular expressions are good enough.

```
([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)

// Can map
.
<blank>
```

I would do:

```
// If you have the decimal point then you require at least on digit after it.
// If there is no decimal point then you require at least one digit.
(([0-9]*(\.[0-9]+))|[0-9]+)
```

Don't think regular expressions are the best way to capture number operator number. The stream operators support this already so prefer to use those.

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::stringstream  lineStream(line);

    double a;
    double b;
    char op;
    char emptyTest;
    if (lineStream >> a >> op >> b && !(lineStream >> emptyTest)) {
        // Enter here if:
        //    1: We correctly read a op and b
        //    2: There are zero extra non-space characters on the line
        //       We find this because the read to emptyTest fails.
    }
```

Declare your variables as close to the location that you use them. This also allows you to initialize them on declaration (which is always nice).

```
// Don't do this.
double a;
double b;
char op;


    // Now you can see the type and know that they are initialized.
    double a  = std::stod(terms[1]);
    double b  = std::stod(terms[3]);
    char   op = terms[2].str().front();
```

Sure you can use a switch that is totally fine. But you can practice using the command pattern in this situation.

```
static std::map<char, std::function<double(double, doubel>> const  actionMap = {
    {'+', [](double lhs, double rhs){return lhs + rhs;}},
    {'-', [](double lhs, double rhs){return lhs - rhs;}},
    {'*', [](double lhs, double rhs){return lhs * rhs;}},
    {'/', [](double lhs, double rhs){
              if (b == 0.0) {
                  throw std::invalid_argument {"Divide by zero"};
              }
              return lhs / rhs;
          }
};


// Now use the action map to find the function you want to call.
auto find = actionMap.find(op);
if (find == actionMap.end()) {
    throw std::invalid_argument {{op}};
}
return find->second(a, b);
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex advice. After submitting the question I rewrote main to use stringstream and it works really good

Answer (score 0):

- What happens if I enter only `+` surrounded by spaces?
- The program should not abort if I enter `0 / 0`, but continue with the next line.
- I'd like to omit the spaces around the operator.
- In the regular expression, the operator part can be written as `[+\\-*/]`.